# How to play a sound without creating a Media Element in Xaml (Windows phone 8)?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, xna

In My case I want to play a sound file from a C# class file. 
I refer the examples with create Media Element in the xaml page. 
I want to play a sound every 5 minutes. This process is behind of my application. I don't have a design page for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your sound is a WAV file, try this:

```
Stream stream = TitleContainer.OpenStream("sounds/bonk.wav");
SoundEffect effect = SoundEffect.FromStream(stream);
FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
effect.Play();
```

**Update**

Please, take into account that [SoundEffect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.soundeffect.aspx) class lives in [Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.aspx) namespace and is part of the [XNA Framework Class Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203940.aspx), which is **not** supported on Windows Phone 8.1 **Runtime apps** (*not* Silverlight one). This means that if you are planning to upgrade/port your application to [universal](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/develop/building-universal-windows-apps) either for Windows Phone 8.1 (and upper) or Windows 8.1 (and upper), this answer will not work for you, unfortunately.

Comment: In my Cage.mp3 file, In the "/Assets/Sounds/Cage.mp3" directory. I use this directory it's through an exception when opening a stream..

Comment: Hi @duDE directory is ok. But Throw an exception at SoundEffect.FromStream(stream); "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object"

Comment: Hi It's working. For .Wav it's works what about .mp3?

Comment: No, unfortunately not - only for WAV

Answer (score 0):

Simply declare your Media Element in code:

```
MediaElement element = new MediaElement();
```

Comment: the following Not Working MediaElement element = new MediaElement();
                element.Volume = 1.0;
                element.Source = new Uri("/Assets/Sounds/cage.wav", UriKind.Relative);
                element.Play();

Comment: This is because MediaElement must be a part of your visual tree. So, the recipe from @Filip is not the way to go under many circumstances.